# Is our universe (not space-time) curved if very distant objects images differ from expected?

Tags: visible-light, astrophysics, curvature, distance

Images of very distant objects are larger than expected and more curiously for even more distant objects the images become smaller.Can this fact suggest that our space(not space-time) is curved which can be compared with a two dimensional sphere surface but with an extra dimension?Could these even more distant objects make focus of their light at the middle distance between its location and the location of our eyes before the light reach our eyes?So the light makes a geodesic instead of stright line...

[image]

[image]

Comment: This video might help. [Gravitational Lensing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Z71RtwoOas)

Comment: This seems to be related as well https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_diameter_distance